# Fixed mount point of external usb hdd

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I'm doing a backup script and need to have a fixed mount point for an external usb drive. If it is the first usb connected it will mount in /media/usb0/, however if it is the second, third... it will mount in /media/LABEL_OF_THE_DISK/. The same apply for sdX. If it is the first will be sdc1 (I have two disks already), but if it is the second will be sdd, third sde....

The hdd is disconnected and only will be connected when is the backup time (once a week)

I may look where is it mounted and pass a parameter to the script as "actual_mount_point", but I'd like to connect the hdd, run the script and backup done, without need be writing anything.

So the question is: Is it possible to have a fixed mount point for an external drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I found out where was the problem. I had in the fstab this line:

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/usb0 auto rw,user,noauto 0 0
```

So when I connected the first USB, it always was mounted in /media/usb0. However now I removed that line, and doesn't matter when I connect the usb, it always is mounting in /media/LABEL

Answer (score 2):

You could also write a udev-rule, which allows you to point what to do when disk connected:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-mount.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="XXXXXXXXXX", RUN+="/path/to/script1.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="XXXXXXXXXX", RUN+="/path/to/script2.sh"
```

You can automate backup on disk connection, for example

Comment: Do I have to create such file? Because I only have 70-persistent-cd and 70-persisten-net rules files. Also the XXXXXXXXXX what represents? The UUID?

Answer (score 1):

you can add an entry to /etc/fstab

get the uuid of your device with blkid (locate/print block device attributes) and make an entry in fstab (hold static informations about filesystem) with that, e.g.
UUID=645a3aa3-09a3-4e9d-bc69-0a5466684137 /media/usb-data/  ext4    defaults        1 1

see "man fstab" for more details

Comment: but this isn't only if I would want to have it permanent connected?

Comment: It will work fine for transient connections too. The device is just skipped if it's not available when `init` invokes `mount -a`. When the device is available, just do `mount /mnt/point`, using the mountpoint specified in `/etc/fstab`.